# HDMI splitter issue

Tags: hdmi, splitter

I have two monitors and one TV screen hooked up to my desk top.

I have a VGA cable going from my video card (VGA Output) to monitor 1.  Then I have an HDMI cable going from the video card (HDMI output) to a SOWTECH
ST-HDSP0001 1X2 HDMI Splitter.  From the splitter I have an HDMI/HDMI cable going to my T.V. and an HDMI/DVI cable going from the splitter to  monitor 2.  When I boot up, the Microsoft logo shows on monitor 2 and the T.V. , but after it boots up it says "no signal" on monitor 2.  I want to mirror monitor 2 on the T.V.

What can I do to make this work?  Do I need to check to see if my cables are HDCP compliant?

I have a Dell desktop.  Windows 10.  i 5 processor.

Sherman

Comment: HDMI cables are not involved with HDCP. HDMI is originally a point-to-point connection. A splitter isn’t a valid device in that topology. This appears to be an active splitter, so it *may* work, but I’m still skeptical.

Comment: Hdmi splitters are very temperamental things and often don't play ball with different signals/pieces of hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same thing and I bought a 1080p rated HDMI splitter but when I hooked it up both devices would show a shaky screen and cap the resolution at 640X480.
I could never get it to work right so I just manually switch the HDMI cords out when I want the other monitor to play.  seems splitters are not a viable technology for monitors only use HDMI splitters if your hooking up a DVD player or something that doesn't auto detect your device.